# S.M.A.R.T data advice

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I've just bought a re-certified WD Red 6tb drive, and I'm attempting to understand the S.M.A.R.T info after running a long scan on WD Data Lifeguard on it.

Would you say this is worth returning? I'm concerned how low some of the Values are.

[image: Screenshot one]

[image: Screenshot two]

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but they look fine to me? I mostly look at the raw values of a few specific ones, BTW, like reallocated sectors and pending sectors. Load cycle count is also interesting. Google western digital and load cycle count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are all stock thresholds for a modern WD disk. no bad sectors or mechanical issues have been detected so far. If you are worried about the 21 for WARN on Spin up Time, that is the standard default (empty) value

Everything looks fine, but be sure to do a `chkdsk -r` to scan the surface for bad sectors. if you do the scan and then see an increase in either `current pending sectors` or `reallocated sector count` (or `Raw Read Error Rate` for that matter), return the disk.

Here are the SMART stats for a healthy WD 1TB Black of mine:
[image]